# flowbite-svelte component props boolean values

Tags: flowbite-svelte

I'm playing around with flowbite-svelte and the NavBar component and setting `fluid=true`

```
<Navbar fluid=true> OR <Navbar fluid="true">
```

but in VSCode it's showing an error that `string is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'`. I'm following https://flowbite-svelte.com/docs/components/navbar#Default_navbar where it states to add `fluid=true` to do full width.

How can I get VSCode to not show this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get VSCode to stop complaining with

```
<Navbar fluid={true}>
```

Including the brackets in the docs might help for folks new to the library who are using TS. Not sure if the same issue occurs for JS.